# How does stdin work when _IOFBF is set in linux

Tags: linux, scanf, buffering

# when _IOFBUF is set, I think the system call read should be called and a
     is set only before the program exits or the buffer is full.But the 
     variable a get input value before the sleep function.#

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    char buf[1024];
    int a;

    setvbuf(stdin, buf, _IOFBF, 1024); // set stdin full buf
    printf("input a:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("a: %d\n", a);
    printf("sleep 5(s)\n");
    sleep(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your guess:

> when _IOFBUF is set, I think the system call read should be called and a is set only before the program exits or the buffer is full

you suppose a logic which isn't applicable to C, at least, without explicit library support: you suppose a postponed execution. The latter is usual for some environments and languages (Javascript-based, Tcl-based, etc.), but not for C.

In C, when an input is requested from your program using `scanf`, that is the place when syscall `read` is executed and the buffer is expected to be filled. Then, this buffer is utilized for reading. A next `read` syscall will be executed when buffer is empty, not earlier; but the initial fill is done, in analog, for the first input request (your `scanf`). And, yep, this is before `sleep`.

If the input is (or can be) a terminal, setting full buffering for it is plainly wrong (and `stdio` doesn't do this by default). With full buffering, `scanf` will return only after the buffer filling (that is, many many keyboard strokes) and/or explicit EOF (Ctrl+D after Enter at Unix/BSD/Linux systems). I guess that's not the behavior you want.

Comment: Yeah. When I set stdout with _IOFBF, syscall write is executed only when program exits or the buffer is full.   So I come to think that stdin would work in the same way, but it proves not to be the case.  Is syscall read executed when the buffer is empty  regardless of full-buffering or line-buffering? If so, stdin and stdout behaves differently(especially the time syscall write and read executes) when _IOFBF is set.

Comment: Yes, flushing output buffer is opposite to filling input one: it can be do only after corresponding `printf`/`puts`/`fwrite`/etc. from user code, and it's postponed until explicit `fflush`, implicit flushing from program termination, flushing full buffer.

Comment: (for your edited comment) Yes, `read` executed to fill an empty buffer. Yes, they behave differently - that's just according to logic of buffer for input and buffer for output.